# OSB 11g: Admin console buttons are disabled

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, weblogic, weblogic11g, osb

I am  new  to OSB and I installed OSB 11g on WLS 11g and login to /sbconsole as weblogic admin. And $subject. Do I have to create any user profile before. For instance IN project explorer page, AddProject button is disabled (all add/delete buttons disabled ). What I have missed here ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you click Create in top-left corner to start a Change session.  WHen you are done your changes you will need to hit Activate button in same top-left corner.